# Turning on the flashlight with Siri

Tags: siri, iphone

I asked Siri to turn on the flashlight but she answered "Sorry but I'm not able to do that". Is there any way to enable Siri to turn on the flashlight? I use an iPhone 6 Plus with iOS 8.1.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried variations - switch on, enable, activate, use..

Comment: @Tetsujin switch on, enable, and activate lead to the same error message. "Use" leads to "You don't seem to have an named flashlight. You could try searching the app store."

Comment: yup, comment was posted before answer - appears the functionality was beta'd then later removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick dash round google gives me the impression that it could do it in iOS 7 beta 1, but the function disappeared after that & was never in a release iOS.

Comment: Thanks, that's unfortunate, I wonder why the function got removed.

Comment: not sure; apparently a few tricks like that came & went around the same time

Answer (score 1):

"Launch Flashlight" used to work. (You had to download one of the flashlight apps from the App store, as the command would not work for the default iPhone flashlight.)

Apple has now de-activated this convenient feature. Why? Who knows.

It was real convenient at night, with the iPhone charging on the nightstand, to simply get some light while in a dark bedroom - like when you wake up in the middle of the night because of a phone call, some noise, or just to go to the bathroom.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Lumos? I mean, it's worth a try.

Comment: I found this funny enough to try it. Sadly, Siri doesn't understand "lumos".

Answer (score 0):

I just tried "launch flashlight" and it worked fine

Comment: which iOS version do you use, and did you install any application to make it work?

Comment: "turn on/off torch" and "turn on/off flashlight" work on iOS 13, with no modifications needed

Answer (score 0):

I'm running iOS 9.3, and I have a Flashlight app. (My specific one is Flashlight Ⓞ by iHandy Inc.
https://appsto.re/us/VKmVw.i)

With this, when I say, "Open Flashlight" it launches the app which in turn automatically turns on the flashlight.

This doesn't directly toggle the Control Center flashlight but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested this in iOS 12 and it works great.

You can also use Siri Shortcuts to say 'lumos' and the flashlight can turn on.

https://twitter.com/bpmarkowitz/status/1015303601839837186?lang=en :)

Answer (score -1):

try using the word "LAUNCH" instead of turn-on.  She was able to turn on my flashlight app.

Comment: Doesn't work for me

Comment: Launch will launch a flashlight app if you have one installed, rather than just turning on the flashlight.